# Does the pagespeed insight API scale for production?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I'd like to use Google's page insight API for a product and may eventually need to make many calls. I was expecting to have a free tier and then a price per call but seems to me to be a limited quota and then I would need to ask for the quota to be raised, and I'm not sure how confident can I be on building a product around it.

Am I missing something?